# How to use multiple delimiters for a java scanner

Tags: java, assembly, java.util.scanner, mips, delimiter

I am tryng to scan through an assembly file where the instruction and registers are separated by white space and commas. My delimiter is:

```
s.useDelimiter("\\s|\\,\\|\\(|\\)");
```

where I am trying to delimit whitespaces, commas, as well as open and close parentheses.

The input is:

```
addi $t0, $t0, 100
addi $a0, $a0,100
```

However even while scanning through I end up with test outputs like:

```
addi
$t0,
$t0,
100
addi
$a0,
$a0,100
```

It wont separate by commas for some reason. My desired output is:

```
addi
$t0
$t0
100
addi
$a0
$a0
100
```

I greatly appreciate your help!

Follow up for Samarth

sw$a0,4($a1)

should be:

```
sw
a0
4
a1
```

I have now found that I also need to delim by dollar signs, so for this example what should the delimiter be?

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly for dollar signs and parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using `s.useDelimiter("\\s?\\$|\\s?,\\s?\\$?|\\s|\\(\\s?\\$?|\\s?\\)");` with this pattern I got output as

> addi
>     t0
>     t0
>     100
>     addi
>     a0
>     a0
>     100

Hey if this is what you are looking for? If not please share any cases where you are not getting result as expected.

Find sample code here at https://ideone.com/0125ZV

Comment: Samarth that is what I'm looking for! What do the question marks do in the delimiter?

Comment: question marks denotes that space occurs once or not at all...Refer java regex https://www.javatpoint.com/java-regex If this please do mark my answer as helpful

Comment: But I don't know why you were using open parenthesis and close parenthesis in your regex. I have removed them. Can you give a test input for parenthesis case though

Comment: sw $a0,4($a1)

should be:

sw
a0
4
a1

I have now found that I also need to delim by dollar signs, so for this example what should the delimiter be?

Comment: @EvanJameson Is my updated answer solved your problem?